# Continuous tracking of location while activity is running

Tags: android, android-intent, location, google-play-services

Apologies for the noobish question, but here goes.

I have an activity A in which a user can place a label anywhere on a map. Upon pressing on this label, another activity, B, is launched, with the label location passed to it.

What I want to do:

Periodically check the users current location against the label location (even if activity B is not visible), and alert the user if they are within a given distance of this location via activity B.

I've already got an intent service to send the location update data, and a broadcast receiver to obtain the data from the service in activity B, but I want both the location updates and the broadcast receiver to stop ONLY once either the activity has been destroyed or if the user is within a desired range of a given location.

How would I go about doing this? Is it even possible to do efficiently for android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your tracking in a service and bind to it. Check this for code snippets: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html